# Crash in PJSUA2 version 2.7 (pjsip 2.11) after accept incoming video call

Tags: android, c++, pjsip, pjsua2

Have update android sip client to pjsua2 2.7 that used pjsip 2.11 and got the crash.

Crash appers only for video call, audio works well.

Seems the problem with codec.

Could anybody help with this error?

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2022-02-24 12:49:04.407 20643-21165/org.test.mobileclient A/libc: Fatal signal 11 
(SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7a39c00000 in tid 21165 (Thread-590), 
pid 20643 (om.mobileclient)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.647 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: Process name is org.test.mobileclient, 
not key_process
2022-02-24 12:49:04.647 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 
*** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-02-24 12:49:04.647 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 
'OPPO/CPH2009RU/OP4C2DL1:11/RKQ1.200903.002/1643076596585:user/release-keys'
2022-02-24 12:49:04.647 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2022-02-24 12:49:04.647 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2022-02-24 12:49:04+0300
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: pid: 20643, tid: 21165, name: Thread- 
590  >>> org.zonatelecom.mobileclient <<<
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10462
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 
(SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7a39c00000
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x0  b400007a39bffe68  x1  
b4000079f0539db8  x2  0000000000000078  x3  b400007a39bfffe0
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x4  b4000079f0539e80  x5   
b400007a39c000e8  x6  8484848383828282  x7  8181818282838383
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x8  89898a8a8a8a8b8b  x9  
8989898989898989  x10 8686878787878888  x11 8686868686868686
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x12 8282828383848485  x13 
8282828282828282  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000000000000000
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x16 0000007a210f7a78  x17 
0000007b2c17a480  x18 00000079faa10000  x19 0000007a20f84293
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000007a20f84268  x21 
0000007a1b9b0cc0  x22 00000000000050a3  x23 000000000000519f
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x24 0000007a1b9b0cc0  x25 
0000007a1b9b0cc0  x26 0000007a1b9b0ff8  x27 00000000000fc000
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000007a1b8b8000  x29 
0000007a1b9af500
2022-02-24 12:49:04.648 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:     lr  0000007a20bb82dc  sp  
0000007a1b9af460  pc  0000007b2c17a428  pst 0000000020001000
2022-02-24 12:49:04.650 959-21948/? W/audio_hw_primary: 
out_get_presentation_position: avail:640 > kernel_buffer_size:640 clamping!

2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0000000000074428  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__memcpy+280) (BuildId: 1ca28d785d6567d2b225cf978ef04de5)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000003dc2d8  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pj_memcpy(void*, void const*, unsigned long)+36) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00000000003dceec  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (write_yuv(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, int, int, int)+760) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 00000000003dc738  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (and_media_decode(pjmedia_vid_codec*, and_media_codec_data*, unsigned char*, unsigned int, int, pj_timestamp*, int, pjmedia_frame*)+1100) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00000000003db740  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (decode_h264(pjmedia_vid_codec*, unsigned long, pjmedia_frame*, unsigned int, pjmedia_frame*)+1800) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 00000000003ded14  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (and_media_codec_decode(pjmedia_vid_codec*, unsigned long, pjmedia_frame*, unsigned int, pjmedia_frame*)+616) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 000000000043d0ec  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pjmedia_vid_codec_decode+88) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000000000043cb9c  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (decode_frame+1160) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 0000000000439874  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (on_rx_rtp+2588) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00000000004274f8  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (srtp_rtp_cb+1316) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 000000000041a6e4  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (ice_on_rx_data+692) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 000000000047c4b8  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (stun_on_rx_data+248) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 000000000048e264  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (on_data_recvfrom+612) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000000000058f9c4  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (ioqueue_on_read_complete+404) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #14 pc 000000000058389c  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (ioqueue_dispatch_read_event+1088) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #15 pc 0000000000586e58  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pj_ioqueue_poll+1696) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #16 pc 000000000037fa80  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pjsip_endpt_handle_events2+472) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #17 pc 000000000030ea4c  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (pjsua_handle_events+92) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #18 pc 000000000030dcac  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (worker_thread+76) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #19 pc 0000000000589824  /data/app/~~k48XH3YNR7vFUGr9_qooKA==/org.test.mobileclient-HR6H_X4BgDzDJi-Q9fOpbA==/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so (thread_main+228) (BuildId: 69dfd2f5d7a61abb87f953b9fe98831da87032c4)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #20 pc 00000000000da278  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 1ca28d785d6567d2b225cf978ef04de5)
2022-02-24 12:49:04.686 22023-22023/? A/DEBUG:       #21 pc 000000000007a448  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1ca28d785d6567d2b225cf978ef04de5)
```

Comment: Have you tried asking on the mailing list, or contacting support/Ming directly about this?

Comment: No, it's an opensource project without hight support. I have created issue on github.

Comment: There is support when you buy the licence. But always try asking on the mailing list first, maybe someone encountered the issue and made a fix that never got pushed upstream